# Jasper report border bottom for multiple lines

Tags: jasper-reports

I would like to draw a dashed bottom border for a text fields which displays its contents in multiple lines.

For example:

```
Address: 104th Street,
         - - - - - - - - - - -- - - - - - - -- - - - - -
         Beside Market Area
         - - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - -- - - 
         Illinois,617273
         - - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - -- - -
```

Currently when i set border bottom to text field it is displaying in this way

```
Address: 104th Street,
         Beside Market Area
         Illinois,617273
         - - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - - -- - - - -- - -
```

Please help me out on how to set border bottom for each line for multi line text

Find my jxml code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_1" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="ab424386-3966-4b59-9892-31b3fdb6c498">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Mysql Adapter "/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[Select "104th Street,\n Beside Market Area\n Illinois,617273" as address from dual]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="address" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="10" y="30" width="122" height="30" uuid="b2d1bb4b-38b0-47e9-8da8-5ce6a31c98a8"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="20"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Address]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement x="150" y="30" width="390" height="30" uuid="40d76fd8-76d0-4d37-8bc7-bb4e48749df2"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Dashed"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{address}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Please attach some relevant jrxml code so that we see what you are doing now... stretchWithOverFlow??

Comment: updated with JRXML code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you manage to break up in separate field in query certainly @mbmast solution is good, but to answer your question I will show you what "crazy stuff" you can do in jasper report.

First I define an `java.util.List` variable that `split` you String on your line breaks. I'm not using `String[]` since this breaks report IDE

```
<variable name="addressArray" class="java.util.List">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[Arrays.asList($F{address}.split("\\n"))]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

Now we can add the `textField` and just get the position of what we want to display. To avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`  use a `printWhenExpression` (to demonstrate this I have put 4 `textField`'s in example)

**Example code**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_1" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="ab424386-3966-4b59-9892-31b3fdb6c498">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Mysql Adapter "/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[Select "104th Street,\n Beside Market Area\n Illinois,617273" as address from dual]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="address" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="addressArray" class="java.util.List">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[Arrays.asList($F{address}.split("\\n"))]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="154" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="10" y="30" width="122" height="30" uuid="b2d1bb4b-38b0-47e9-8da8-5ce6a31c98a8"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="20"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Address]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement x="150" y="30" width="390" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="40d76fd8-76d0-4d37-8bc7-bb4e48749df2">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{addressArray}.size()>0]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Dashed"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{addressArray}.get(0)]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="150" y="60" width="390" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="fcba83d9-5a57-45b4-b015-b23a12043784">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{addressArray}.size()>1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Dashed"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{addressArray}.get(1)]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="150" y="90" width="390" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="d39e756a-7e2b-409d-a423-2a8df5dd7378">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{addressArray}.size()>2]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Dashed"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{addressArray}.get(2)]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="150" y="120" width="390" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="12fe3b4f-2b13-4b3a-98ae-adc834f89bc1">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{addressArray}.size()>3]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Dashed"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{addressArray}.get(3)]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

**Result**

[image: Split result]

Answer (score 3):

Break your address up into separate fields (i.e. **address-line-1**, **address-line2**, etc. instead of everything in **address**).  Then use `<printWhenExpression>` to conditionally include that line (if it is not blank or null).  For those that are to be included (i.e. the meet your condition) you can include a nested `<staticText>` field for the separator line.